# using LINQ to get the top N percent of a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have been trying to find a way for LINQ to be able to select the top n% of a given list. The closest I have been able to get is the take statement which works similarly to the TOP PERCENT SQL statement but doesn't support percentages. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I just can't quite seem to see it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470339/linq-version-of-top-percent?rq=1

Comment: There's no direct method, but you can use `Count()` to determine the total number of items, and then use `Take()`, with the parameter being `(desiredPercentage * totalItems) / 100`.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the source is an `ICollection<T>` (and not just an `IEnumerable<T>`), you can do something like that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakePercent<T>(this ICollection<T> source, double percent)
{
    int count = (int)(source.Count * percent / 100);
    return source.Take(count);
}
```

Note that it could work with an `IEnumerable<T>` (using the `Count()` method), but it would enumerate the sequence twice, which is usually considered a bad thing.

Comment: Probably best to to just call `.ToList()` in that case then :)

Comment: @Khanzor, it's not necessarily a good idea. What if it's very cheap to get the count of the collection, but expensive to retrieve all its content? There is an example of such a collection [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)

Comment: my suggestion to call .ToList() was for an overload of IEnumerable :). It's trivial to think of examples of collections where the count is easier to return than the content (e.g. select count(*) v. select *), so I agree with you, and apologise for the ambiguous comment.