# LINQ - Select top 10% of elements

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ I have to select the top 10% of a List ordered (asc) by "Score" value. The model has Id and Score.

Example:

If I have 100 items and each of one has a score, i want them ordered by Score (asc) and only select the top 10 (10%)

What I've done so far:

```
var orderedList = (from Emps in db.Emps
                  orderby Emp.Score ascending
                  select Emp);
```

Then I have to count the `orderedList` and calculate the 10% and do another query.
I want to be all in the same query if its possible.

How do I do this?

Comment: check this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328130/using-linq-to-get-the-top-n-percent-of-a-list

Comment: I didn't found that! thanks!!

Comment: if this answered your question accept it as an answer so that others can benefit from it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `Take(int count)` extension method:

```
var result = values.OrderBy(t => t.Score).Take(values.Count * 10 / 100);
```

Or if you want to always take at least 1 value you can use `Math.Ceiling`:

```
var result = values.OrderBy(t => t.Score).Take((int) Math.Ceiling(values.Count * 10 / 100d));
```

Comment: What is "values" in my code? would it be my orderedList?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes this would be your collection, where you hold your values.